# Spring Security Core Plugin doesn't work on Grails 3.0.8

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-3.0

I just installed Grails 3.0.8 , created an app, and installed the Spring-Security-core plugin whose version is 3.0.0.M1. And then, I followed the steps of [tutorials](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/tutorials.html) of the plugin.

But, the authentication does not work well. It means that I cannot access top directory page, http://localhost:8080, always the error message is shown on page. The error message is "Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.".

How can I make the plugin works well?

Following steps are that I did.

1. create-app using comand

   ```
   $ grails create-app testApp profile=web
   $ cd testApp
   ```
2. "Install" the plugin by adding it to build.gradle

   ```
   dependencies {
      …
      compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1'
      …
   }
   ```

Run the compile command with interactive mode.

```
    $ grails 
    grails> compile
    grails> exit
```

3. Create the User and Role domain classes with interactive mode.

   ```
   $ grails 
   grails> s2-quickstart common User Role
   ```
4. Edit grails-app/init/BootStrap.groovy to add a test user.

   ```
   import com.testapp.Role
   import com.testapp.User
   import com.testapp.UserRole
   class BootStrap {

      def init = { servletContext ->

         def adminRole = new Role('ROLE_ADMIN').save()
         def userRole = new Role('ROLE_USER').save()

         def testUser = new User('me', 'password').save()

         UserRole.create testUser, adminRole, true

      }
   }
   ```
5. Start the server with interactive mode.

   ```
   grails> run-app
   ```
6. navigate to http://localhost:8080.
7. input "me" on user field and "password" on password field, and click submit.

   Then, the message is shown on the page

   ```
   Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.
   ```

Note:

the application.groovy is shown below, but I made no change.

```
    // Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'common.User'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'common.UserRole'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'common.Role'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        '/':                ['permitAll'],
        '/error':           ['permitAll'],
        '/index':           ['permitAll'],
        '/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],
        '/shutdown':        ['permitAll'],
        '/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],
        '/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],
        '/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],
        '/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],
        '/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll']
    ]
```

Comment: Did you annotate your controller?

Comment: Which controller is the top directory?

Comment: I added my default conf file, application.groovy, to this question. The configration makes all user are able to access to top directory, "/". –